# What is the solution number of the equation $x^2-x+1\equiv 0 \pmod{p^e}$

Tags: number-theory

What is the solution number of the equation

$$x^2-x+1\equiv 0\pmod{p^e}$$

I know when $e=1$, it is $1+\left(\frac{-3}{p}\right)$, and I guess it is the same for $e>1$, but can anyone provide a proof?

updated:

I know when $e=1$, the number is 
$$
1+\left(\frac{-3}{p}\right)
$$

When $e>1$, it is said that the answer is the same, saying that 
$$
1+\left(\frac{-3}{p}\right)=1+\left(\frac{-3}{p^e}\right)
$$

That's what puzzling me.

Comment: How exactly did you obtain that result for $e = 1$?

Comment: @TMM, like the answer bhattacharjee is given. But I need to show $\left(\frac{-3}{p^e}\right)=\left(\frac{-3}{p}\right)$

Comment: I don't think so. We have $\left(\frac{-3}{5}\right)=-1,\left(\frac{-3}{25}\right)=-1$

Comment: Let me rephrase that: $$\left(\frac{-3}{p^e}\right)=\left(\frac{-3}{p}\right)^e.$$ So the equality is false if $e$ is even and $\left(\frac{−3}{p}\right) = -1$. In your example, $\left(\frac{−3}{25}\right) = 1$.

Comment: @TMM, what is the solution of $y^2\equiv-3\pmod{25}?$

Comment: @lab There is no solution. *"...But, unlike the Legendre symbol, if $\left(\frac{a}{n}\right) = 1$ then $a$ may or may not be a quadratic residue $\pmod n$..."* [(Wikipedia)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_symbol)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $p>2,$$$p^e\mid (x^2-x+1)\iff p^e\mid (2x-1)^2+3$$

So, $$(2x-1)^2\equiv-3\pmod{p^e}$$

Applying [Discrete Logarithm](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DiscreteLogarithm.html) w.r.t some primitive root $g\pmod {p^e}$,

$2ind_g(2x-1)\equiv ind_g(-3)\pmod{p^{e-1}(p-1)}$ as $\phi(p^e)=p^{e-1}(p-1)$

Using [Linear congruence theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruence_theorem), the last equation is solvable iff $(2,p-1)\mid ind_g(-3)\iff 2\mid ind_g(-3)$ and in that case it has exactly $(2,p-1)=2$ solutions.

Now we can prove,  $-3$ is a quadratic residue of $p^e,$ iff it is a quadratic residue modulo $p$ (See below)

So, the number of solutions of $$(2x-1)^2\equiv-3\pmod{p^e}$$  is $0=1-1$ or $2=1+1$ i.e. is $1+\left(\frac{-3}p\right)$ for all prime $p>3$

[Proof:
Now,  if $-3$ is a quadratic residue modulo $p^s$ so there exists an integer $y$ such that $p^s\mid(y^2+3)\implies y^2+3=a\cdot p^s$ for some positive integer $a$

Now, $(y+b\cdot p^s)^2+3=y^2+3+2y\cdot b\cdot p^s+b^2p^{2s}=a\cdot p^s+2y\cdot b\cdot p^s+b^2p^{2s}$

If $p^{s+1}\mid (a\cdot p^s+2y\cdot b\cdot p^s+b^2p^{2s})\iff p\mid (a+2b)$ if $2s\ge s+1\iff s\ge 1$

$\implies 2b\equiv-a\pmod p$

so if $y^2\equiv-3\pmod{p^s}$ is solvable so will be $y^2\equiv-3\pmod{p^{s+1}}$

Using induction we say $-3$ is a quadratic residue of $p^e$ if it is  a quadratic residue of $p$ for $e>1.$

Again if for $e>1,p^e\mid(y^2+3)\implies p\mid (y^2+3),$ 
so if $-3$ is a quadratic residue of $p^e,$ then it is a quadratic residue modulo $p$

So,  $-3$ is a quadratic residue of $p^e,$ iff it is a quadratic residue modulo $p$]

Comment: Yes, I know it. But I have to show that $\left(\frac{-3}{p^e}\right)=\left(\frac{-3}{p}\right)$, is there such conclusion?

Comment: Wonderful proof! Thank you very much!

Comment: @hxhxhx88, but the indices with respect to different moduli may vary, right??

Comment: What indices?..And I'm still have a problem, why (3) is solvable iff $(2,p-1)|ind_g(-3)$?

Comment: @hxhxhx88, please have a look into http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruence_theorem

Comment: ..........Yeah...It is quite obvious...I must be drunk..

Comment: @lab: See the edit to see how you can add tags to equations here.

Comment: @hxhxhx88, please find the edited answer as the value of discrete logarithm/indices of $-3$ may vary with the change of moduli.

Comment: @TMM, thanks for your formatting.But m the earlier solution was faulty, the reason mentioned in the above comment.

Comment: May I request the down-voter to explain the mistake here.

Comment: @labbhattacharjee, oh I understand the problem in your original answer, and the new one is good, thank you!

Comment: @hxhxhx88, my pleasure. We can further show that $\left(\frac{-3}p\right)=1$ if $p\equiv1\pmod 6$

Answer (score 2):

There's a much easier solution: $x^2-x+1$ is a multiple of $p^e$ if and only if $(x^2-x+1)(x+1) = x^3+1$ is a multiple of $p^e$ and $x\not\equiv1\pmod p$. (Here it is important that $-1$ is not a root of $x^2-x+1$, which is true for all primes but 3.) And the congruence $x^3\equiv-1\pmod{p^e}$ means that $x^6\equiv1\pmod{p^e}$ but $x^3\not\equiv1\pmod p$, which means that $x$ has order 6 modulo $p^e$. In other words, the roots of $x^2-x+1$ modulo $p^e$ are exactly the elements of order 6 modulo $p^e$ (for $p\ne3$). Since the multiplicative group modulo $p^e$ is cyclic (for $p$ odd), the number of such elements is 2 if $6\mid (p^e-1)$ and 0 otherwise.

Similarly, the roots of the cyclotomic polynomial $\Phi_n(x)$ modulo $p^e$ are simply the elements of order $n$. The above is the case $n=6$.

Comment: There is a typo, it should be $6\mid p^e-1$, anyway, a beautiful proof! Thank you!

Comment: you're welcome! thanks for catching the typo - fixed

Comment: 3 is enough instead of $n=6$, since $-x$ has order 3 ;)

Comment: Equivalently, $3\mid p^e-1$ if and only if $6\mid p^e-1$. We've reproved the fact that most primes are odd!